# What are the various ships and their stats in Sky Force Reloaded?

Tags: sky-force-2014, sky-force-reloaded

Quite a while ago I had fun playing through Sky Force 2014.  I decided to redownload it and play it again for a while, but to my pleasant surprise, I noticed that the developers had recently released a new, updated version *Sky Force Reloaded*.

Much of the game seems to be quite similar to the earlier version, however, one major difference is that you can collect ship parts and once you've collected all parts for a specific ship, it is unlocked and you can select it for play.

Although I have no way to specifically farm a particular ship, I am still curious, what are all of the available ships and what are their buff/debuff stats?

Comment: They released an update tonight which adds a brand new level (9) and new upgrades to the ship. The weekly tournaments also start as of today.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The planes have been finally complete in the latest update.

1. Model 2004 a.k.a The Classic : your original red ship. Laser whip will replace main cannon after receiving the 'score bonus + new weapon for the classic' card. No more retro mode.
2. Enforcer: Main cannon damage +10%
3. Iron Clad: Health +50%, speed -10%
4. Swift Justice: -50% health, speed +10%. It has the narrowest cannon coverage (focused shots).
5. Ambulance: increase rescue speed, low health. It has the widest cannon coverage (3-way shots).
6. Limp Berserker: Max firerate, low health
7. Ace of Spades: increased card hunting luck, low health
8. Gladius: More Firepower, Short Weapon Range
9. Octopus: fires mini-rockets.

[image: Ambulance (after the latest update)]
[image: Swift Justice (after the latest update)]

Comment: Yeah, I'm thinking those last two will come in futre updates. Just a guess.

Comment: I take that back.  I just got a Black wing piece for #8.  I guess you can earn these ships.  Maybe #9 will come from an update.

Comment: Ok, another ship was added today.  It looks like Ships #8 and #9 were not previously available and, I assume, now #8 is after the recent update.  Once you complete ship #8, please post the details and I'll give you the answer mark since this will be the complete list as of today.  Thank you.

Comment: I got tired of waiting on offering the answer mark.  When ship #8 is released, please update this answer. :D

Comment: Sorry to hijack the thread, but can someone tell me how on earth you chnage ships? I cannot seem to find it anywhere!

Answer (score 3):

I only unlocked 3 so far. If I am not wrong, you can only get parts of a certain ship from certain stages?  At least that is how its going on me with unlocking ships.  Got drops at easy difficulty levels.

Download and run previous version of skyforce - Enforcer. Main cannon damage +10%

Stage 1 - Iron Clad. +50% Health -10% Speed

Stage 2 - Swift Justice. -50% Health +10% Speed

Stage 3 - Limp Beserker.  Max firerate, ridiculously low health (1 hit KO)

Stage 8 - Ambulance. Increased rescuse speed, ridiculously low health

Hope this helps :P.  Cheers

Edit:  apologies if I got the stages wrong

Comment: Yes, you do get a ship for playing SF14.  I have that ship. It's called Enforcer and gives +10% Main Cannon damage. It's my go to ship.

Answer (score 2):

Ace of Spades - Increased luck at card hunting, ridiculously low health